How do this in JPA crteria
I have this :
@Entity
@Table(name = "cycle")
public class Cycle extends BaseBean {
    // ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cycle")
    private List<SousCycle> sousCycle;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sous_cycle")
public class SousCycle extends BaseBean {
    // ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_sous_cycle")
    private List<Processus> processus;
    // ...
}

@Entity
    @Table(name = "processus")
    public class Processus extends BaseBean {
    // ...
    // no @OneToMany or @ManyToOne or Other
    // ...
}

Is possible to have a Json in API REST with JPA?
I have tried this, but I didn't have information about Processus in Json.
@Repository
public class CycleDaoImpl extends BaseDaoJpaImpl implements ICycleDao
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CycleDaoImpl.class);

    @Override
    public List<Cycle> findTousLesCycles()
    {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriabuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Cycle> criteriaQuery = criteriabuilder.createQuery(Cycle.class);
        Root<Cycle> cycleRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Cycle.class);
        Order codeAscOrder = criteriabuilder.asc(cycleRoot.get("code"));
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(codeAscOrder);
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        cycleRoot.fetch("sousCycle", JoinType.LEFT);
        TypedQuery<Cycle> cycleTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        List<Cycle> cycleListeResultat = cycleTypedQuery.getResultList();
        return cycleListeResultat;
    }
}

